# Act 2 Chapter 3, how to progress after defeating swarm?

Tags: gears-5

I've defeated the swarm/flock in the lab area, but the doors that should be enabled for progress aren't and it seems like I am stuck. While I heard the typical "end of combat" musical cue, the main combat music is still playing. Any idea how to get the game to progress passed this point? Otherwise, I am stuck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After wandering around the room for awhile after defeating the swarm/flock, I approached the desk with ammo to the right of where you enter the room. For some reason that caused the combat music to subside and I was able to progress through the doors that I thought I should be able to. Hopefully this helps someone else...

Comment: You can now 'accept' your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you defeat the flock. After you've defeated the flock, hold down LB and make sure the objective, 'defeat the flock' is crossed out, and be able to go through the double doors. If the objective 'defeat the flock' is not crossed out, press start and restart from the last checkpoint.

Comment: I had already defeated the flock. The objective didn't get cleared out until I performed the steps described in my answer, but you don't need to restart the checkpoint. Of course, maybe this has been patched out and is moot at this point....